# jquery and jquery.ui work in all browsers except IE 7 - Why?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have written a small jquery application that allows a person to slide a handle 200 px to the right.

The application uses jQuery 1.2.6 and jquery UI 1.5.3

My script works flawlessly in all browsers except ie 7 (ie 6 untested, don't care).  It even works in ie 8.

to see the code app in action and the code via view source, please check out http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com.

iphone-unlock.js is the jquery code, which uses style.css specifically for the graphic elements. Sorry it's very slow - caching is turned off while I debug.

Also, there are no errors for debugging.  Any thoughts on why this is happening are greatly appreciated.

I thought it may be helpful to add the code in an edit:
$(document).ready(function()
{

```
var unlock = function()
{

    $.openPopupLayer({
        name: "iPhoneInteract",         
        url: "/sites/all/themes/tao/templates/iphone.html",

        afterClose: function () {
            $("#unlock-handle").animate({"left" : "-1"} );
            $("#slide-to-unlock").animate({opacity: 1}, 200 );
        top.location.href = 'http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com/?device=desktop';
        }
    });


}



$("#unlock-slider").slider({
    handle: "#unlock-handle",
    animate:true,
    slide: function(e,ui)
    {
        $("#slide-to-unlock").css("opacity", 1-(parseInt($("#unlock-handle").css("left"))/120));
    },
    stop: function(e,ui)
    {
        if($("#unlock-handle").position().left == 210)
        {
            unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#unlock-handle").animate({left: 0}, 200 );
            $("#slide-to-unlock").animate({opacity: 1}, 200 );
        }
    }
    }
);
```

});
    enter code here

Comment: If this is the only code you've written so far, **start using the latest versions.** jQuery 1.2.6 is ancient, almost 3 years old at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 has a problem with animation if two conditions are true:

- A containing DIV has position: relative, AND
- The property being animated is not set (in this case "left")

Looking at the style.css, it appears you are setting a value for "left," but #unlock-bottom does have position:relative so it's unclear if the IE7-specific issue applies. It might be helpful to debug with the animated elements in a container that does not have position:relative to see if the problem goes away.

See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-animation-issues-ie7-position-relative/

Comment: Thank you! After reading the article you sent, I made adjustments to the position elements.  Although I'm still working on the issue, at least now the animate behavior is erratic instead of simply nothing at all. Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 0):

First, try using the latest versions of both (jQuery 1.5.1 / UI 1.8.9). There's no reason to rely on outdated code, there are hundreds of bugs fixed between rele

Comment: Unfortunately, you're right, but switching to such drastically different versions of jQuery will likely break parts of the existing code (if there are any).

Comment: It's true that I wrote this code a while back. Specifically, it was written for the content management system Drupal, which still uses 1.2.6.  i did try to upgrade but I did encounter more bugs than normal, so I figured easier to stick with what works.